# What does static variable in general mean for various programming language and circumstances?

Tags: c++, objective-c, vb.net, static

Static variables are usually: (in most programming languages) shared, persistent, and allocated on the code section of the program

But what does that have anything to do with the word static? What is so static about that? I thought `static` means doesn't change?

For example, in vb.net static is written shared and that means a member function that can be accessed without object instantiation. Static within function usually means that the variable life time is the life time of the whole program. It seems that static variables are stored on the code section of the computer. Am I correct in my understanding based on the example?

Comment: It means static storage AFAIK.

Comment: Does it really need to *mean* anything? If we said "frobbly" instead of "static" wouldn't the concept be the same?

Comment: @Jon By convention we as programmers, declare variables with a significative name. I guess it's the same for language developers when they create keywords.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: Yes, but variables and types are named with a view to the data model we have constructed for the problem domain. Language keywords are chosen with very different criteria. For example historic consistency is very important, even more so than being accurate from a linguistic point of view. So while of course keywords *should* be self-describing, that's not all there is to it.

Comment: If it was named "frobby" of course it wasn't consistent with history, and afterall even if it was, was harder to remember.

Comment: The computing industry, led by Microsoft, has very often appropriated English words and used them for concepts that have at best a very tenuous link to their original meaning.  Add in the differences between British English and American English, and you very soon learn not to rely on your knowledge of non-technical  English to understand concepts in computer science.

Comment: @SList The computing industry is not led by Microsoft.  Especially with regards to things like the meaning of `static`; Microsoft is a relative late-comer, and didn't even exist when it got its meaning.  (Microsoft is very innovative in marketing speak, but not so much in technical vocabulary.)

Comment: @JamesKanze - I did not write that the computing industry is led by Microsoft!!  I meant, that Microsoft has imposed more of its own interpretations of English words on the industry than anyone else.  Consider the huge number of words used in Windows and Office, whose Microsoft meaning we all now take for granted.

Comment: It means a world of hurt in unit tests :)

Comment: @GordonM Then change your unit test framework.  I've never had any problem with `static` variables in unit tests.

Comment: @SList I can't judge Windows or Office, but we're talking about `static` here.  Which was established in C before Microsoft was founded.

Comment: @jamesKanze - it was just a general point about english and technical words.

Comment: @JamesKanze Statics are basically global state.  Global state is poison to modular software.  Modular software is much easier to test than stuff that depends on global state.

Comment: @GordonM You're confusing visibility with persistence.  Statics are (semi-)persistent state.  And a unit test framework which can't deal with persistent state isn't worth bothering with.

Comment: @JamesKanze A static is visible to all instances of a given class.  A public static is visible to the entire codebase.  That makes them global (or semi-global in the case of non-public statics).  In a single-threaded application of < about 100 KLOC you can manage them, but as soon as concurrency enters the picture or the codebase gets big enough they will become increasingly problematic.

Comment: That's the essence of this question. How do I relate the static concept in computer science with spoken english. If there is any connection at all.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, I think the keyword is appropriate. It means the variable you declare as static will remain stored at the same location throughout the whole execution of your program.

> I thought static means doesn't change

This corresponds to the `const` keyword. Const implies it doesn't change, static implies it doesn't "move", as to it stays stored at the same location.

Comment: Any instance of a variable will be stored at the same location for as long as the variable lives.  The key meaning behind static is that there is no coming and going of the variable.

Answer (score 8):

In general, what doesn't change with something that is static in
a programming language is whether it is alive or not.  Static
variables are always alive; they have a single instance which
comes into being either at the beginning of the program or the
first time they are visible, and lasts until the end of the
program.  Non-static variables come and go, as blocks are
entered and left, or as class instances are created and
destroyed.

In C++, for reasons of C compatibility, static, when applied to
variables at namespace scope, has a completely unrelated
meaning: it means that the variable has internal, rather than
external linkage, and is not visible in other translation units.
Why the word static was adopted for this in early C, I don't
know; I can only guess that they needed something, and didn't
want to introduce a new keyword.  (Originally, in the very
earliest versions of C, variables at file scope obeyed the rules
of a Fortran named common block: all variables of the same name
referred to the same storage.)  Looking back, of course (with 20/20
hindsight), the default for variables at file scope should have
been internal linkage, with a special keyword (`public`?) to say
that the variable had external linkage.  But this was a lot less
obvious in the early 1970's.

Answer (score 3):

Static is referred to the variable storage. Inside a function call, every variable that you declare is pushed on the stack. Unlike other variables, a static variable isn't pushed on the stack, it's like a global variable, that survives the whole execution of the program, with the difference that is visible only inside the block is declared.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have to learn the meaning of "static" in computer science, and not relate it to spoken English.  Especially as it applies to variables and functions, with slightly different outcomes in C.

Comment: That's the essence of this question. How do I relate the static concept in computer science with spoken english.

Comment: That's the point of my answer - there is no gain by relating the two.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the word from http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/static?s=t

1. pertaining to or characterized by a fixed or stationary condition.
2. showing little or no change: a static concept; a static relationship.

A static variable is one that maintains its state even after it goes out of scope as opposed to a non static variable which would be re-initialised every time it came back into scope - so can be thought of in terms of having a *"stationary condition"* or exhibits *"no change"*

Answer (score 1):

If you can avoid it, just don't go into static for C++. In any modern language static just means there's only ever one instance and it's never destroyed. That's not too far a stretch from the English meaning, and leads nicely to a discussion of const/final/readonly and what that means.

Answer (score 1):

Static variable means ,there is only one copy of the variable,even if you create multiple instances of the class.That is, all objects of the specified class use the same memory location.Or if you want an example,say , we have two threads .On first thread you create a progressbar and on the second you need to update it.In this case you can define a static variable in your progressbar's  class to store the  progress and create one instance of the class in each thread.One thread for initialising and in the other you change the value of static variable.Since both use the same copy the progress will be available in the first thread.
So static means something that doesnt change its location on creating a new instance..Or we can say something tha preserves its state ;) Blah blah blah